# authentication process using partial views in a .Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, partial-views

I wish to develop a Website using Angular js and .Net MVC. But still I wish to develop it as an SPA(Single page application).  I am supposed to develop an eCommerce site and my client is short of time. To speed up things I don't wish to learn authentication process in Angular Js and then implement it. I am already aware about server side authentication in .Net MVC applications. So my question is can I implement authentication process using **partial views** in a .Net MVC applications (so as to keep it as an SPA) ?

Any help/Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default when we implement the asp.net mvc templates using scaffolding it will help to create the Accounting options setting a connection to local sql express database. That would be work without a single line of code and also implemented using partial views once logged in. Check out that options!!!